# Differences between ways of initializing a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm learning Swift and was wondering what the differences were between these ways of initializing an empty dictionary?

```
var emptyDic = Dictionary<String, String>()

var emptyDic:[String:String] = [:]

var emptyDic = [String:String]()
```

and will this:

```
var emptyDic:[String:String]
```

create an un-initialized dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1 and 3 are almost syntactically equivalent since the 3rd one is a shorthand notation of the first. But after the declaration of 1, 2 and 3 they are semantically the same. So it is more a personal preference (for me the 3rd one :) rather than a huge difference.

However the 4th example is (as you said) uninitialized and the compiler will warn you if you want to access it too early.